# Mathematica equivalent of a curl snippet

Tags: web-access, internet

Is there any documentation anywhere on how to convert an invocation of `curl` into the Mathematica equivalent (using for example `URLExecute` or `URLRead` with `HTTPRequest`)?

The specific `curl` code I am having trouble converting to a Mathematica equivalent is

```sh
curl -X POST --data 'Expected RESPONSE.' "https://postman-echo.com/post"
```

where I use the example API from [this service](https://docs.postman-echo.com/?version=latest). My attempt to convert this was

```
URLExecute[HTTPRequest["https://postman-echo.com/post",
<|Method -> "POST", "ContentType" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
"Body" -> ExportString[{"Expected RESPONSE." -> ""}, "JSON"]|>]]
```

but I did not get the results consistent with what is produced by `curl`. What would be the right way to use Mathematica functions for this example? I know I can just use `RunProcess` with `curl` if need be, but I want to assume I cannot or will not be able to use `curl` itself (e.g. on a Windows computer where I cannot install `curl`).

Either answers to my general or specific inquiry would be appreciated.

Comment: This appears to give the same result as `curl` on my machine. Can you elaborate on what is inconsistent?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a program like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to compare the requests being generated by both:

Your call to `curl` generates a request like this:

```
POST https://postman-echo.com/post HTTP/1.1
Host: postman-echo.com
User-Agent: curl/7.65.0
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Expected RESPONSE.
```

Your WL code generates a request like this:

```
POST https://postman-echo.com/post HTTP/1.1
Host: postman-echo.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Wolfram HTTPClient 12.
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 28

{
    "Expected RESPONSE.":""
}
```

As you can see, you are not sending JSON from curl, but you are from Mathematica. So you just need to get rid of the `ExportString`:

```
URLExecute[HTTPRequest["https://postman-echo.com/post",
<|Method -> "POST", "ContentType" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
"Body" -> "Expected RESPONSE."|>]]
```

And the request will now be similar:

```
POST https://postman-echo.com/post HTTP/1.1
Host: postman-echo.com/pos
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Wolfram HTTPClient 12.
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 18

Expected RESPONSE.
```